# convert a JAR file to a .pkg.tar.xz(Installable arch archive used by pacman)

Tags: arch-linux

How do I convert a JAR file to a .pkg.tar.xz(Installable arch archive used by pacman)? Is there any maven plugin or some tool to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Jars don't know anything about pacman and its usage. Either your distro, arch-linux, knows how to handle jar files, or it doesn't.

I know jars of 2 kinds:

- Executable programs which are packed as a jar, which is essentially a zip archiv of mainly the .class-files, combined with a some manifest files, which specify, where to find the main class.
- But libraries are shipped as jar files too.

To run the program, you ideally just have to call

```
java -jar /PATH/TO/the.jar
```

Maybe your DE has some mechanism to run such jars by clicking on them.

Comment: Is there any maven plugin to do the job?

Comment: A maven plugin for arch-linux? I'm sorry, I didn't learn maven. And I'm not informed, how to write packages for pacman.

Comment: Okay Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

.jar - Java ARchive - an archive format used by Java language

.pkg.tar.xz - a package of some kind, archived by `tar` and compressed by `xz`

You can think of it, as you have a book in one language, and you want to give to someone who does not know that language. Possible with a translator, of course, but...

Comment: There is one plugin called deb-maven-plugin that compiles A Jar and a Debian package.